# SendMessage scrolling doesn't work in MS Word with found SPY++ handle

Tags: c#, ms-office, cpu-word, handle, spy++

I want to simulate mouse actions as scrolling by SendMessage for opened applications i.e. Chrome, Word etc. I need some functionality like in X-Mouse Control or AHK.
I checked the handles with SPY++ and it works, if i take the found handle of Chrome.
Why is it not working with the word handles, shouldn't it? (I checked them all in my code.)

Word handles:

[image: SPY++ found Word handles]

My code:

```
e.Handled = true;

int handle = int.Parse("004A0618", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

SendMessage((IntPtr)handle , WM_SCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_PAGELEFT, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Sadly i can't log messages with SPY++ in several application like Office and Chrome with the Finder. It works in IE. As suggested it also doesn't work, if i start and stop the logging. Nothing appears. The "All Windows in System" option works but i can't figure it out what i have to filter. Nothing when i search for "Scroll" etc.

Would it make a difference if i use mouse_event/SendInput?
(I tried to implement it but it always let my VS crash.)

Comment: Hmm -- what is `WM_SCROLL`? I thought you had to specify the type of scrolling message? Like `WM_VSCROLL` or `WM_HSCROLL`

Comment: WM_SCROLL = 276, SB_PAGERIGHT = 1 (I found it on a chinese site).
WM_HSCROLL and SB_PAGEDOWN is the same. Both doesn't work in Office (Word, OneNote).
I'm not chinese but i tried a lot of things, it's so frustrating. Can't find an answer. Now i  try to implement SendInput simultaneously but i guess it's a special way for Office?!

Comment: No. `WM_HSCROLL` is 276. `WM_VSCROLL` is 277. There is no such thing as `WM_SCROLL`. Don't take code off of sites other than the documentation sites. So that code is trying to scroll horizontally, not vertically. Read about WM_VSCROLL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-vscroll

Comment: Yes, i created the variable for testing and it scrolls but not in Office. Don't know where to search for a solution.